# Draw pentago in python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to draw a convex hull on random points but i have to do this using with opencv.(Not convexhull command or scpiy or hull lib)

- First step i create random points between 14 - 20 numbers .

How can i save `plt.show()` graphic and draw convex hull like this:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
points = []
points_limit = 12+random.randint(0, 7)
print(points_limit)

for x in range(points_limit):
    points.append([random.randint(0, 9),random.randint(0, 9)])

print(points)

for point in points:
   plt.scatter(point[0],point[1], color='k', s=100)

print(points)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You know, the random points are non unique.

Comment: @Attersson Are u talking about second pic ?

Comment: I am talking about the code snippet used for generation of random points. If you are unlucky you could end up with only 1 or 2 unique points